# What regex can I use to match date format and time format?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to retrieve the date and time from a string that looks like:
"filename_20170818_010138.xml" I'm currently using

```
(@"(?<date>\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)")
```

Which works for the date, but what could be the best way to get the time aswel
in a seperate group?

Comment: 1rst ty to get some documentation about regex especialy the Quantifier part. then to convert to c" datetime you can use this.

Comment: In addition to Cosmin Cretu answer I will add a `\.` at the end of the regex to match the dot before the extention to be sure that if the Filename ends with 8 digits I don't get the wrong block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@"(?<Date>\d{8})_(?<Time>\d{6})"
```

This will give you a Date group and a Time group. Use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`.

Answer (score 0):

With out regex I would have done it like this:

```
string input = "filename_20170818_010138.xml";
var splitResult = input.Split(new string[] { "_", "." }
                        , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var data = DateTime.ParseExact(splitResult[1] + splitResult[2]
                                , "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
                                , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to handle filename with `_` or `.`
You can replace `[1]` and `[2]` by `splitResult.Length - 3` and `splitResult.Length - 2`. I let out of bound exception handeling to you.